# Tallying Majority Consensus From Nested Struct

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

How do I tally the votes of a nested struct to find out majority consensus?

as an example, if we have following scenario below; I want to create a function which allows me to calculate whether majority consensus among voters is "Yes" for true.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.10;

contract Consensus {

    struct Vote {
        address voter;
        bool yes;
        string comment;
    }

    struct ConsensusResult {
        Vote[] collectiveVotes;
    }

    mapping (bytes32 => ConsensusResult) votes;

    function addVote(bytes32 _voteID, bool _vote, string memory _comment) public {
        uint _length = votes[_voteID].collectiveVotes.length;
        votes[_voteID].collectiveVotes.length++;

        Vote storage v = votes[_voteID].collectiveVotes[_length];
        v.voter = msg.sender;
        v.yes = _vote;
        v.comment = _comment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main constraint to keep in mind is you want to always organize things so you can complete the needed operations with functions of O(1) complexity, so they will have a consistent gas cost at any scale.

In practical terms, avoid unbounded for loops and recursion (The stack depth limit will probably "get you" before it runs out of gas).

The naive way is to iterate and count them up. The O(1) way is to "invest" as you go, so recall of the tally is trivial.

```
struct ConsensusResult {
    Vote[] collectiveVotes;
    uint yesCount;
}
```

...

In `addVote`

```
if(_vote) votes[_voteID].yesCount++;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the addition to addVote is that the naive or O(1) invest way? I want to do it properly

Comment: example is the O(1) way because there is no iteration. It will cost the same gas every time, every step of the way.

Comment: never mind @Rob I managed to figure it out a O(1) approach based on your input, thanks for hinting, I was trying to make something simple really complicated